# Sort C# Mongo find results to match array of items that was searched for

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Background: We are using ElasticSearch separate from our mongo to search for things. Once the query returns a list of id's we need to pull the items from mongo and have them sorted in the order they came from ES.

Question: How do I find a list of id's then sort the results to be in the same order that the list is. It would maybe be something like this:

```
// NOTE: The following code does not work.
JobsCollection
  .Find(Builders<JobModel>.Filter.In(j => j.Id, idList))
  .OrderBy(j => idList.IndexOf(j.Id))        // <-- Something like this
```

I may just sort it after I get the objects if I can't figure it out, but if the mongo driver can do it for me, that would be cool.

Comment: Can you sort `idList` in a reproducible manner or is it arbitrarily sorted?

Comment: idList comes sorted from our search. Its order depends on the weight that they had for the term that was searched.

Comment: Are you okay using non type safe  version ? What is mongo server  version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a good way to make a sorting you described on MongoDB server side. And even if it was possible I doubt you gain some performance improvement comparing to client side sorting. The most time will be spent for reading the data from DB and transfering to the client, which are equal for server and client sorting.

Your LINQ solution looks good for me. However it uses `List.IndexOf()` for each list element that gives you complexity of O(n^2). This LINQ could show poor performance on big lists.

I propose to improve it and create a dictionary that maps id value to its index in the list:

```
var idMap = idList.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);

var sorted = JobsCollection
    .Find(Builders<JobModel>.Filter.In(j => j.Id, idList))
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(j => idMap[j.Id]);
```

This will give you complexity of O(n * log(n)) which is far better.

**UPDATE** (regarding not working code from the question):

I believe by not working code you mean that it could not be compiled. The problem is that `Find` method returns `IFindFluent<TDocument, TDocument>`. `IFindFluent` is an cursor and you can't use it in LINQ expressions directly. To make your code compile and work add `.ToEnumerable()` call on `Find` result:

```
JobsCollection
    .Find(Builders<JobModel>.Filter.In(j => j.Id, idList))
    .ToEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(j => idList.IndexOf(j.Id));
```

Comment: If the result set is large and the sorted field is indexed (and can be sorted by the server), its better to sort it on the server side. Otherwise, it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: There is no way to perform described sorting on server side.And indexing the field does not influence sorting speed.

Comment: You are correct, there is no way to perform this particular sort on the server, that is why I added the caveat "and can be sorted by the server". As for index usage with sorts, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-and-index-use and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Sort-Operations. Indexes are required for large sorts server-side and in the case of an indexed field being used for the sort, MongoDB will try to use that index to perform the sort.

Comment: For the pure performance aspect of sorting server vs client side, it does depend on a lot of factors. In general, database servers have considerably more resources at their disposal to perform things like sorts. There are definitely balances to be struck here with respect to resources on the db client vs db server.

Comment: To clarify, the code in my question doesn't work at all. The Mongo driver can't unwrap my lambda to be executed on mongo. I will try your code.

Comment: Check update of my answer regarding not working code.

Comment: I originally had `SortBy()` there instead of `OrderBy()`, but that gave me the error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the serialization information for j => Convert(value(RepairWise.Data.Repositories.JobRepository+<>c__DisplayClass6_0).ids.IndexOf(j.Id)).'`
I realized it couldn't automatically send the list to the mongoserver for sorting. That's when I came here. I think I like your dictionary version. When we implement paging we won't have to worry about bogging down memory or anything, either.